# Opening of a specific camera in Froyo and Pre-Froyo devices

Tags: android

After Gingerbread, it is required to pass the camera id (the integer) when we want to open the camera like Camera.open(integer cameraid).

Does anyone how to open a specific camera (front or rear facing) in Froyo and Pre-Froyo devices ?.

The reason I am asking is because Froyo and PreFroyo's Camera open method (API 8) does not accept any input integer id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-Gingerbread, only one camera per device was supported, so there is no way to open other cameras.  So there should be no devices running on Froyo or earlier releases with multiple cameras.

If such devices exist, then the vendor must have added an API extension to access the additional camera devices; you'd have to ask the vendor about that.

Also note that you can still call Camera.open() without an integer argument on Gingerbread and later - it's guaranteed to open the first rear-facing camera on the device.